# React Native change animation of scene on the fly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

With React Native, when defining the `Navigation` component, we're able to set the animation type, for example:

```
<Navigator
     configureScene={() => {
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid;
     }}
```

Is there anyway to change this SceneConfig on the fly? For example if I'm pushing to a new Scene, I'd like to float it in from the right, however if I pop back a scene, I'd like to float it in from the left.

I don't see anything in the docs regarding this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom animation for each route by adding `sceneConfig` property to your route object.

Example:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/NavigatorExample.js#L60